# He gains happiness "by" or "from" watching flowers?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

What is the right preposition in this sentence, *by* or *from*?

1. He gains happiness ***by*** watching flowers.
2. He gains happiness ***from*** watching flowers.

Comment: I'd think you'd only gain boredom from watching flowers.

Answer (score 1):

Both sentences work and in this context, they mean similar things.

In general, the prepositions **from** and **by** work similarly for *verbs*, but differently for *nouns*. For example, the sentences *I gain happiness **from** flowers* and *I gain happiness **by** flowers* mean different things. The former means that the flowers themselves give you happiness, while the later means that being in proximity to flowers gives you happiness.

In the above sentence, the inclusion of **watching** makes the sentence acceptance for both.

Answer (score 0):

Either is correct, and they mean essentially the same thing.

Comment: Thanks! Fixed now. It wasn't letting me delete it at first. Still getting used to the interface here.

Comment: @Ethan Do we just take your word for it; or are we permitted some citation to prove your opinion ?